# Introduction to Functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I'm a codeacademy student getting along with Javascript. I'm very lost trying to solving a way to Fix the function on line 9 Making sure the syntax is right. I have also to Call the greeting function once it is fixed!

```
var calculate = function (number) {
var val = number * 10;
console.log(val);
};

// Badly written function with syntax errors!
greeting var func{name}(console.log(name)))}
```

Comment: Clearly, the syntax doesn't match up.

Comment: Why are there so many end parens?

Comment: @9Deuce Because it's a homework problem OP is supposed to correct.

Comment: It seems like you have to revisit the section about functions. Not quite sure what exactly you want from us. If CodeAcademy doesn't present the information in a way you understand, then maybe look at other tutorials, such as http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions .

Comment: It's so basic that I'm even surprised you took time to post the question. Just check **any** tutorial, any article and you will see hundreds of examples of functions declarations or expressions. From there you will for sure figure out correct syntax to declare a function. There is even one example in your own code..

Comment: codeacademy **is** a tutorial.

Comment: So follow the example above it...

Comment: You have the correct function syntax in your example itself!

Comment: I'm sorry im not experienced. As a said, I have the task to organize e fiz whats wrong in the code, also use the 'greeting'.

Comment: var <functionName> = function (<parameterList>) { <functionBody> }

Answer (score 1):

I think it should look like this

```
var greeting = function(name) {
  console.log(name);
}
```

The parameters go inside parentheses and the function body goes inside the brackets.

To call the function just enter the function name followed by an open parenthesis followed by a string containing the value of a name, followed by a closing parenthesis. It looks like this

```
greeting('myName');
```

Let's take a look at what was wrong with the example

```
greeting var func{name}(console.log(name)))}
```

1. Greeting should come after var, so we're properly declaring the variable
2. `func` is incorrect syntax. Use the keyword function
3. Instead of brackets after function, it should be parentheses to store parameters
4. The function body should go inside brackets instead of parentheses
5. There are 2 extra closing parentheses that result in a syntax error

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand all the jokes, its my homework.

Comment: To call it : greeting('Felipe');